# anatomically correct without sexual connotation

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language

I would like to be able to describe something as anatomically correct in the sense that I would have a doll, etc. that is essentially anatomically accurate, without conveying the sense that I am primarily referring to the accuracy of the sexual parts of the doll.

I would like to use this to refer to dolls that both have and do not have sexually accurate organs if possible.

Is there a simple and accepted expression?

---

After comparing search results for images using the suggested answers, I believe realistic is the best answer for this question. As is often the case, multiple answers are of good quality.

Comment: To me *"anatomically accurate"* has much less of a sexual connotation than *"anatomically correct"*. But probably some people would misinterpret it anyway.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "anatomically correct".  It's the mind that's dirty, not the doll.

Comment: You can get an [anatomically correct skeleton](http://www.brightminds.co.uk/anatomically-correct-skeleton/p14?source=froogle&utm_source=froogle&utm_medium=comparison_shopping_feeds&utm_nooverride=1&gclid=CP-c27W08skCFQqdGwodDnUCvw). Surprisingly it appears to have no genitals...

Comment: @AndyT--Surprisingly?  Do skeletons normally have genitals?

Comment: 'anatomically correct' is literally correct but was initially created as a euphemism for 'having external genitalia'. And it's kind of hard to write something more literal than what it already is. So you are looking for a phrase that just does not have the genitalia connotations? Just to clarify, what is correct anatomy in a doll that does not have genitalia (it would be incorrect to leave them out right?) Does it include internal organs? Is the doll supposed to look  accurate from the outside with clothes or without clothes? Or what?

Comment: @AndyT: But appearances can deceive! Skeletons seem to reproduce somehow -- they far outnumber live humans, for instance. ;-)

Comment: @StevenLittman - The ellipsis at the end of that statement was intended to convey sarcasm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A doll that is exceptional for the accuracy of its representation of the human form, at whatever scale, and whether or not that extends to genitalia  (which are likely to be covered by doll clothes anyhow), may be termed a ***[realistic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/realistic)*** doll.

> 3. resembling or simulating real life: *a realistic decoy. (Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary,* 2010).

Answer (score 6):

**"An anatomically correct doll"** is the right term for them.  I believe the ones you refer to are meant for educational purposes.

> [**An anatomically correct doll**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomically_correct_doll) or **anatomically precise doll** is a doll with some of the primary and secondary sex characteristics of a human. In colloquial vernacular it usually refers to the genitals being depicted (after all, typical dolls are approximately anatomically correct with regard to most other parts of the anatomy). This can be for realism or educational purposes, as well as to satisfy inanimate fetishism. A very detailed type of anatomically correct doll may be used in questioning children who may have been sexually abused. The use of dolls as interview aids has been criticized, and the validity of information obtained this way has been contested.

Here is the picture of an anatomically correct doll.[image]

Comment: @Centaurus- I up-voted your answer, but I would **much prefer it** if you deleted everything after "educational purposes," which is off-topic and may be distasteful to the OP (as it is to me). Thank you for your consideration and your otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: @MarkHubbard  I think my answer will be incomplete without a reference and link (in this case a paragraph from Wikipedia).  I also think the picture of a doll depicting male genitals is not offensive in itself.  I'm sorry that you find it offensive.

Comment: @Centaurus- It's only the part of the paragraph after "purposes" that I find off-topic and offensive. Why is it necessary to quote the entire paragraph when you have already included a link to the article? I have great respect for you and always appreciate your answers and comments, but in this specific instance, I think you are including too much information that is off-topic in your response. I have no objection to the photo whatsoever; I think it was brilliant of you to include it!

Comment: @MarkHubbard I can't see anything offensive in the paragraph you mentioned. It says that some police psychologists have used anatomically precise dolls to question children who were sexually abused in order to get precise information about who did what to them. A touchier situation is the mention that such dolls may be used by pedophiles. Although it shocks most of us, pedophiles do exist. and we cannot ignore or else we may be encouraging them. In addition to all this, there are no vulgar terms or the use of language. – Centaurus

Comment: @MarkHubbard If the community find it offensive, I will certainly remove the whole paragraph, though. – Centaurus

Comment: @Centaurus I upvoted your answer. Do you think my post needs deleting? I would like to have your opinion. I am thinking about deleting it.

Comment: @Centaurus I don't mind downvotes. I posted it because the OP seemed to be asking for a neutral term in terms of sexual connotation. Does life-size have any sexual connotation?

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your feedback. I deleted it once and undeleted it. Merry Christmas! :-)

Comment: @Centaurus- I edited your post to reflect my sensibilities but primarily to be able to withdraw my up-vote. I accept your comments but continue to believe that a discussion of fetishism and child sexual abuse, however well intended, is still off-topic on EL&U, without a disclaimer from you to the effect that you realize it is off-topic but still important to be considered (I've done just that in one case recently). Feel free to undo my edit, if it is accepted in peer review, and to say what you want. I still respect you and hold you in the highest regards, whatever you decide to do with this.

Comment: @MarkHubbard   1. I've approved your edit.  2. Was that sentence what was bothering you?  That could be easily removed without spoiling my answer.  As a matter of fact I've seen them in shop-windows in Paris near the Moulin Rouge. I'm not the kind of man who goes to sex-shops.   3. I agree that a discussion of fetishism and child sexual abuse is certainly off topic here.  4. I dare you to spot such instances in my answer.  5. No hard feelings.

Comment: @Centaurus- You are a prince, kind sir! The part of the quoted paragraph in your answer that reads, "as well as to satisfy inanimate fetishism. A very detailed type of anatomically correct doll may be used in questioning children who may have been sexually abused. The use of dolls as interview aids has been criticized, and the validity of information obtained this way has been contested," is off-topic and adds no value to your answer, in my opinion. I'm glad we're still friends. :-)

Comment: @MarkHubbard 1. That's a quotation from Wikipedia.   2. I do think that part of the quoted paragraph adds some information about these dolls.  3. Let's see what other members say about it.

Comment: @Centaurus- 1. I forgive you for *that* :-) (even though the overweening arrogance of the wiki crew occasionally approaches that of *Bono*); 2. it definitely adds information about the dolls, but the OP stated, "without conveying the sense that I am primarily referring to the accuracy of the sexual parts of the doll. I would like to use this to refer to dolls that both have and do not have sexually accurate organs if possible"; and 3. Let's see, I agree. You still get an up-vote from me!

Answer (score 1):

If "without" means you want a phrase that does not refer to the sexual characteristics of the doll, consider

> ### [**Lifelike**](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=lifelike&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on)
>
> "Like a living being; resembling life; giving an accurate representation; as, a lifelike portrait. — Life"like`ness, n. Poe." — [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)
>
> ---
>
> "[Lifelike robotic cats are now toys for seniors](http://www.cnbc.com/2015/11/18/lifelike-robotic-cats-are-now-toys-for-seniors.html)" The headline of a C.N.B.C. online news article regarding premium pet robotic cats ([Wayback Machine (W.M.) link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119152507/http://www.cnbc.com/2015/11/18/lifelike-robotic-cats-are-now-toys-for-seniors.html)).

I didn't filter A.R.T.F.L. Project's search results, so you might also notice this definition from[The American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/]) by Noah Webster "A. Like a living person." which I thought I'd also mention it demonstrates that the word usually describes the images a person, albeit it does not do so exclusively as those cat dolls demonstrate.

Sometimes, lifelike is used in the context of anatomically correct dolls, such as on this [J.C. Penny webpage](http://www.jctoys.com/newborn-baby-dolls-s/1829.htm) ([W.B.M. link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905054131/http://www.jctoys.com/newborn-baby-dolls-s/1829.htm)) or in the Daily Mail article entitled [Disturbing or a fuss over nothing? Controversy over diaper change boy doll sold at Toys R Us because it has life-like genitals](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2711579/Thats-no-Besty-Wetsy-Parents-pissed-Toys-R-US-selling-doll-pees-pants-anatomically-correct-penis.html#ixzz3vAO7xbXE) ([W.B.M. Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023121846/http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2711579/Thats-no-Besty-Wetsy-Parents-pissed-Toys-R-US-selling-doll-pees-pants-anatomically-correct-penis.html)). However please do notice that in those contexts, more specification is added to convey *just how* the dolls are lifelike (the jctoys website also uses the phrase anatomically correct). As far as I know, it is not an inherent signification of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***true-to-life*** doll

> true to life: consistent with reality, realistically represented. [Early 1800s ] [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/true-to)